# material-ui v4.0.1 warning "Expected an element that can hold a ref"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I upgraded to material-ui v4.0.1 and I see that Modals now require a forwarded ref. I'm having some trouble implementing a fix for this using class components and Dialogs.

I tried using `React.createRef()` as well as `React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (...)` in a few places but I can't figure out how to resolve this warning.

In my parent component I render a custom component

```
<ApolloFormDialog />
```

In `ApolloFormDialog` I render essentially:

```
<Dialog ...>
  {title}
  {subtitle}
  {form}
</Dialog>
```

---

The full warning is `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Modal'. Expected an element that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally use a plain function component for an element instead?`

However I am using class components currently. Migrating to use function components is not an option right now as my app is rather large.

---

I have tried adding a ref to `ApolloFormDialog` as

```
<ApolloFormDialog ref={React.createRef()} />
```

as well as wrapping `ApolloFormDialog`'s class with:

```
export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <ApolloFormDialog ref={ref} {...props}/>)
```

and then adding that `ref` to the dialog as

```
<Dialog ref={this.props.ref} />
```

but the warning still persists, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces this problem. Nothing about version 4 will force you to convert class components to function components. The warning is saying that the `children` of the `Modal` are the problem, however `Dialog` controls the children passed to `Modal` so it would be helpful to see a reproduction of the problem in order to fully diagnose what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @RyanCogswell. I added my code to CodePen and was unable to reproduce, which was frustrating, so from there I started to delete props on my Dialog until it was in the same state as the CodePen example, and it turns out after deleting a prop `TransitionComponent`, the warning went away.

I'm unsure if this is a bug in v4, but it may be worth creating an issue if I can reproduce the issue with this prop in a CodePen.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My issue didn't actually have to do with `Dialog`, but with the prop `TransitionComponent` on `Dialog`.

I switch between two types of transitions in my `ApolloFormDialog` depending on if the screen is below a certain breakpoint, which was being called as function components:

```
<Dialog
  open={open}
  onClose={onRequestClose}
  classes={{
    paper: classnames(classes.dialogWidth, classes.overflowVisible),
  }}
  fullScreen={fullScreen}
  TransitionComponent={
    fullScreen ? FullscreenTransition : DefaultTransition
  }
>
  {content}
</Dialog>
```

`FullscreenTransition` and `DefaultTransition` come from a file and are defined as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade'
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide'

export function DefaultTransition(props) {
  return <Fade {...props} />
}

export function FullscreenTransition(props) {
  return <Slide direction='left' {...props} />
}

export function FullscreenExpansion(props) {
  return <Slide direction='right' {...props} />
}
```

Changing these functions to the following fixed my issue:

```
import React from 'react'
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade'
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide'

export const DefaultTransition = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Fade {...props} ref={ref} />
))

export const FullscreenTransition = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Slide direction='left' {...props} ref={ref} />
))

export const FullscreenExpansion = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Slide direction='right' {...props} ref={ref} />
))
```

---

This was a relatively hard issue to solve on my end, so I'm going to leave this question up just in case someone else runs into a similar issue somewhere down the road.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also create a class vs a stateless component out of it and that would solve it (typescript doesn't like the above solution)

Answer (score 36):

I have had the same problem with "@material-ui/core/Tooltip" wrapping a new functional component. Even if the component was wrapped in a div inside its own code.

```html
<!-- "Did you accidentally use a plain function component for an element instead?" -->

<Tooltip>
  <NewFunctionalComponent />
</Tooltip>

<!-- Wrapped in a new div, devtools won't complain anymore -->

<Tooltip>
  <div>
    <NewFunctionalComponent />
  </div>
</Tooltip>

<!-- No more warnings! -->
```

Comment: +1! Was also using `Tooltip` when I encountered this issue. `React.forwardRef()` did not work for me. It would eliminate the warning but would not show a `Tooltip`. This solution worked however.

Comment: wrap in Box worked for me!  Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. Wrapping the Tooltip content in a div did the trick to avoid a warning message!

Answer (score 11):

Wrapping my component to another div inside material-ui transition componet (like Slide, Fade etc) solves my issue.
Example code:

**From**

```js
<Slide direction='Right' in = {isSideNavOpen} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
      <MyComponent />
</Slide>
```

**To**

```js
<Slide direction='Right' in = {isSideNavOpen} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
     <div><MyComponent /></div>
</Slide>`
```

Answer (score 8):

`React.forwardRef` fixes the issue for me, too.

To ensure that the `React.forwardRef` solution works with Typescript, you must implement the following as per the documentation in Material-UI:

```
const Transition = React.forwardRef<unknown, TransitionProps>(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

See the source code in their demo [here](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#transitions).

Comment: Yep, forwarRef fixed this for me too when working with Material UI Modal components. const SomeModal = React.forwardRef(function Modal({orgInfo, handleClose}, ref) { ... })

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error

> expected an element that cand hold a ref

I solved by adding a `<Box></Box>` surrounding my children component.

**From**

```
<Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
    <DetailsCard />
</Modal>
```

**To**

```
<Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
  <Box>
    <DetailsCard />
  </Box>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by wrapping my functional component in a div.
In my case the problem ocurred with a Tooltip component wrapping a custom functional component.

```
<Tooltip tittle={...}>
       <CustomFC />
</Tooltip>
```

And the solution was

```
<Tooltip tittle={...}>
    <div>
       <CustomFC />
    </div>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: This is actually the easiest approach that I've found to solve this problem.  I had a situation where I had a conditional render inside of a Modal component.  My first approach was to use React.forwardRef, but I couldn't modify the props for one of the components, so I wound up wrapping the modal in <div></div> and the warning went away.