# React MUI <Tab> component "Expected an element type that can hold a ref."

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I am working with [React MUI Tabs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/) and am running across:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef(ButtonBase)`. Expected an element type that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally provide a plain function component instead?`

I have read many threads, [Including This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347839/material-ui-v4-0-1-warning-expected-an-element-that-can-hold-a-ref) -- And surrounding my element in a `<div>` or a `<Box>` does not do the trick.

I have also read [This Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs) Which suggests that it's "just a warning" to me even though I am not trying to pass a `ref`.

Can anyone find what is wrong with the following (if anything):

```
<Tab label="Project Info" {...a11yProps(0)} component={() => (
    <Box onClick={() => setValue(0)}>
        <Icon sx={{color: ywpBlue}} title="Grid View">info</Icon>
        <Typography sx={{fontSize:"20px"}} mt={-3}>
            Project Info
        </Typography>
    </Box>
)}/>
```

I have also tried:

```
<Tab label="Project Info" {...a11yProps(0)} component={props => 
    <Box {...props} onClick={() =>
```

To no avail.

The `<Tabs>` display fine, and function as expected ..  I just HATE seeing red "Warnings" in my DevTools Console.

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but maybe `component={<Box onClick={() => setValue(0)}>`?

Comment: Can't use component like that .. React would assume you were exporting a literal, and `<Box` couldn't be reached as a "component".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tab` component doesn't have a prop `component`. Under the hood, `Tab` is using `ButtonBase`, hence when it is being provided `component` it complains. If you want to just add an Icon and style, you should follow the docs on customizing tabs [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#icon-position). You can provide an Icon, and center the label and styled like so:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
import Tab, { TabProps } from "@mui/material/Tab";
import PhoneIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Phone";
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

const CustomTab = styled(Tab)<TabProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  "&.MuiButtonBase-root": {
    fontSize: "20px",
    marginTop: -3
  }
}));

export default function IconTabs() {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <CustomTab icon={<PhoneIcon />} label="phone" />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

If you need more control, you could consider using `TabUnstyled` in the base library and you will have complete control of the components show in the [base docs](https://mui.com/base/react-tabs/)

Comment: You know I didn't use the `icon` property because it wouldn't align to top ..  Even if I set it to `iconPosition="top"` (which is default) ..    I went back and viewed my theme and there was an override: `flexDirection: "row",` --  This is the definitive answer on the proper way to display the icon ..